# Can I use RADIUS for strongswan - psk configured?

Tags: vpn, radius

I'm a beginner for the strongswan server.
And I was looking through the configuration examples from the strongswan.org.

It seems the strongswan server should be configured to use EAP authentication to use RADIUS.
Can anybody confirm this?
Or please let me know if this is wrong understand.

Actually I configured a strongswan server with PSK authentication and was thinking to add RADIUS server but could realize it may not a possible option but still I'm not sure 100%.

If you have any comments here about it, it would be helpful for me.
Thanks,

```
              Ki
```